# Resize image background iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

Hi I have  developed an app for ios 7 and the 3.5 display , actually i am applying all the auto layout constraints needed for the 4 inch display but for me it´s not clear if once i apply auto layout the background image will resize to fit the 4 inch display or if i need to have a new background image to fit in the 4 inch display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the image compatible with the **4-inch** display and set the `ImageView` `contentMode` property to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` in the storyboard or in your code. So no matter what the screen size is, it will automatically be adjusted and the image will not even get pixelated.

Comment: How do i add it in the storyboard?

Comment: Go to you `Storyboard`, Click on your `ImageView`, Select the `Attribute Inspector` window from right side panel and underneath the `View` heading, you would be able to see a property `Mode`.Then select `AspectFit` option from that drop down menu.

Answer (score 1):

From memory, I believe it would stretch/shrink the image if you used the same image and allowed to automatically resize. I think that the best course would be to have two images and set the proper image programmatically, deepening on UIDevice's idiom property.

If you don't care if the top and bottom edges get cut off on the smaller screen, you could simply make the UIImageView the size of a 4-inch screen, delete any constraints, and center the view. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That depends on `.contentMode` property. The default value of this property is `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`. In this mode your image will be stretched to fill UIImageView's bounds. But you might be interested in `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or
   `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` in order to preserve aspect ratio.